# Nesting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nested

I have a problem with nesting of lengths please suggest me the best way of solving this. my problem is as follows.

I have some standard length lets say **Total length** (This is the total length which we need to fill with some specific length blocks)

input is list of length blocks eg: 5000, 4000, 3000

and gap between each block is a range eg: 200 to 500 (this gap can be adjusted with in the range)

Now we have to fill the Total length with the above available length blocks with gap between each block and that gap should be with in the gap range given above.

Please suggest me some way of solving this problem.

Thank in advance...

Regards,
Anil

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem and what solution are you expecting? This problem is reminding the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which are NP-Complete. Also: What is the range of lengths, and what is the size of the input?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is essentially the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) with a small twist.  You can use the same pseudo-polynomial time solution as subset sum: create an array of length "total length" (which we call *n* from now on) and, for each length *k*, add it to every existing length in the array (so if element *m* is populated, create a new entry at *m + k* (if *m + k ≤ n*), but leave the existing one at *m* as well), as well as creating a new array entry at location *k* representing the creation of a new set.  You can build up a set of entries at array element *i* to represent the set of lists of length blocks totaling *i*.  Each set entry should link back to the array entry it came from, which it can do by simply storing the last length that got you there.  This is similar to a question I answered recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612601/120169), which you can adjust to allow duplicates as you see fit.

However, you need to modify the above approach to account for the gaps.  Let's call the minimum gap between each element *x* and the maximum gap *y*. When adding an entry of length *k*, we include the minimum gap whenever adding it to another entry (so if *m* is populated, we actually create the entry at *m + k + x*).  We continue to create the initial entry at *k* because we include the gaps between elements.  When we create an entry, we can also determine if it fills the space.  Suppose the new entry contains *t* elements and has total *m*.  Then it fills the space iff *m ≥ n - t* ( *y - x* ).  If it fills the space, we should add it to a solution list.  Depending on how many solutions you want, you can terminate the algorithm as soon as enough solutions are found, or let it find all solutions.  At the end, simply iterate through the solutions list.

Anything within the range can represent its gaps in any of a number of different ways, but one way that works is to greedily allocate the "slack" - for example, if you are 1000 away from the new total length using your above example, you can pick the first three gaps to be 500 (which is 300 extra slack each, for 900 total extra) and then the fourth to be 300 (for the extra 100 slack, totaling 1000) and every additional gap should be minimum (200).

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply. There can be n number of length blocks as input. there is no range for block size we can enter any length. we have to fit the Total length with any of the length blocks available from list of length blocks and we can repeat the same length blocks multiple times.

Comment: @Martin: Your initialization doesn't work, because you don't know the number of gaps and thus don't know the sum of all minimum gaps.

Comment: Hi Martin and Wolfram, could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: @WolframH thanks for pointing this out.  I have modified the answer to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Martin, your solution is bit confusing for me, could you put your answer in programmatic way. I need this solution quickly please help on this. Thank in advance

Comment: @anil I may code this up for fun at some point, but not immediately.  Sorry about that!