# Variant of subset sum

Tags: performance, algorithm

I read through all subset sum topics and still have issues with implementing the algorithm for the following problem.

Given the array A of N integers (N<=20) where

- a[i]<=20
- values do not have to be unique

and an integer K (K<=20).

**Rules**:

- Array items equal to K are "covered" with K.
- If sum of two or more array numbers is equal to K, these numbers are also covered.
- Each number in the array can be covered only once.

**Example**:

N=6, integers: 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

**K=4**

**Possible coverages**:

1. coverage

   - 4 is covered.
   - 1, 1, 2 are covered as 1+1+2=4.
2. coverage

   - 4 is covered.
   - 1, 3 are covered as 1+3=4.

**K=5**

**Possible coverages**:

1. coverage

   - 5 is covered.
   - 1,1,3 are covered as 1+1+3=5.
2. coverage

   - 5 is covered.
   - 1,4 are covered as 1+4=5.
   - 2,3 are covered as 2+3=5.

**Goal:**

For given array A and integer K, find all possible "coverages". I need all coverages, not only one which covers most of the array items.

**I have tried with two approaches**:

1. **Brut force algorithm**.
   Checking all possible subsets of all possible sizes works, but takes too much time even for only 10 numbers. I need it to finish in no more than 500ms.
2. First, I sorted the array in descending order. Then for each possible number of sub-sums I create "slots". I loop through the array and put numbers in the slots following the rules like:

   - Put number in the slot if its sum becomes equal to K.
   - Put number in the slot having the least sum of all slots.
   - Put number in the slot which gives the closet sum to K of all slots.

Well, the second approach works and works fast. But I found scenarios where some coverages are not found.

I would appreciate if somebody offered idea for solving this problem.

I hope I explained the problem well.

Thanks.

Comment: this doesnt sound like a variant of the subset sum problem, this sounds exactly like the subset sum problem. Your entire post can be summarized as "i need all subsets of a set S, whose elements sum to K"

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ready answer for that, but I recommend to take a look on 'Bin packing problem' it  could be usefull here.

The main problem is to find all possible sums giving number K. So try this:

```
Collection All_Possible_Sums_GivingK;

find_All_Sums_Equal_To_K(Integer K, Array A)
{
    /* this function after finding result
    add it to global Collection AllPossibleSumsGivingK; */
    find_All_Elements_Equal_To_K(Integer K, Array A); 

    Array B = Remove_Elements_Geater_Or_Equal_To_K(Integer K, Array A);

    for all a in A {
        find_All_Sums_Equal_To_K(Integer K-a, Array B-a) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified this from an earlier answer I gave to a different subset sum variant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612601/120169

I am running it here on the K=8 case with the above numbers, where we reuse 1 in two different places for one of the two "coverages".  Let me know how it works for you.

```java
public class TurboAdder2 {
    // Problem inputs
    // The unique values
    private static final int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    // counts[i] = the number of copies of i
    private static final int[] counts = new int[] { 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    // The sum we want to achieve
    private static int target = 8;

    private static class Node {
        public final int index;
        public final int count;
        public final Node prevInList;
        public final int prevSum;
        public Node(int index, int count, Node prevInList, int prevSum) {
            this.index = index;
            this.count = count;
            this.prevInList = prevInList;
            this.prevSum = prevSum;
        }
    }

    private static Node sums[] = new Node[target+1];

    // Only for use by printString and isSolvable.
    private static int forbiddenValues[] = new int[data.length];

    private static boolean isSolvable(Node n) {
        if (n == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            while (n != null) {
                int idx = n.index;
                // We prevent recursion on a value already seen.
                // Don't use any indexes smaller than lastIdx
                if (forbiddenValues[idx] + n.count <= counts[idx]) {
                    // Verify that none of the bigger indexes are set
                    forbiddenValues[idx] += n.count;
                    boolean ret = isSolvable(sums[n.prevSum]);
                    forbiddenValues[idx] -= n.count;
                    if (ret) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                n = n.prevInList;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void printString(String prev, Node n, int firstIdx, int lastIdx) {
        if (n == null) {
            printString(prev +" |", sums[target], -1, firstIdx);
        } else {
            if (firstIdx == -1 && !isSolvable(sums[target])) {
                int lidx = prev.lastIndexOf("|");
                if (lidx != -1) {
                    System.out.println(prev.substring(0, lidx));
                }
            }
            else {
                while (n != null) {
                    int idx = n.index;
                    // We prevent recursion on a value already seen.
                    // Don't use any indexes larger than lastIdx
                    if (forbiddenValues[idx] + n.count <= counts[idx] && (lastIdx < 0 || idx < lastIdx)) {
                        // Verify that none of the bigger indexes are set
                        forbiddenValues[idx] += n.count;
                        printString((prev == null ? "" : (prev + (prev.charAt(prev.length()-1) == '|' ? " " : " + ")))+data[idx]+"*"+n.count, sums[n.prevSum], (firstIdx == -1 ? idx : firstIdx), idx);
                        forbiddenValues[idx] -= n.count;
                    }
                    n = n.prevInList;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int value = data[i];
            for (int count = 1, sum = value; count <= counts[i] && sum <= target; count++, sum += value) {
                for (int newsum = sum+1; newsum <= target; newsum++) {
                    if (sums[newsum - sum] != null) {
                        sums[newsum] = new Node(i, count, sums[newsum], newsum - sum);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int count = 1, sum = value; count <= counts[i] && sum <= target; count++, sum += value) {
                sums[sum] = new Node(i, count, sums[sum], 0);
            }
        }
        printString(null, sums[target], -1, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I translated your Java code to C#. This works very fast, yet there are possible inputs for which my C# version does not work. Please, can you test the algorithm with the following inputs. data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, counts = new int[] { 1, 1, 2 }, target = 3. data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, counts = new int[] { 1, 1, 2 }, target = any_number_greater_than_6. I'm going to analyze your solution further and will let you know if I improve it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Marko: Yes, I see the issue.  The problem is that we need to actually keep track of all of the sum sets we have seen thus far, instead of the shortcut being used.  We can make a tweak to relax the line in isSolvable() from "if (forbiddenValues[idx] + n.count <= counts[idx])" to "if (forbiddenValues[idx] == 0)" but we'll get duplicate sum sets.